# Adding and removing from a string containing dates using PHP

Tags: php, string, date

I have to edit a whole bunch of date intervals. But they are all mixed up. Most are in the form `Month YearMonth Year`

eg `January 2014March 2015`

How would I insert a hyphen in between so I end up with

`January 2014 - March 2015`

I also have the problem where these dates occur in the same year.

eg `April 2012September2012`

In such a case I would need to insert the hyphen and remove the year so that I'm left with

`April - September`

There must be some PHP string operators for stuff like this. Well thats what I'm hoping.

Would appreciate some guidance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well if we don't see any code we can't fix any code. Also have you tried something to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, sorry for my delayed reply

```
$string = "January 2014March 2015";
preg_match('/([a-z]+) *(\d+) *([a-z]+) *(\d+)/i', $string, $match);
print "$match[1] $match[2] - $match[3] $match[4]";
```

outputs,

January 2014 - March 2015

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$string = "January 2014March 2015";
$res = preg_replace('/(?<=\d)(?=[A-Z])/', ' - ', $string);
echo $res,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
January 2014 - March 2015
```

Comment: thank you for your alternative solution. would you know how to remove the years if its in the same year?

Comment: @Modboy: That's not possible using preg_replace. But with your own solution, you just have to compare `$match[2]` and `$match[4]` if they're equal, don't print them.